# Getting OutOfBoundsException while pagination a String

Tags: android, string, pagination, indexoutofboundsexception

I am creating an epub reader for android. For the pagination part, I am trying to get the whole string content and then search for space in the string. Then I get the text height and compare it with the screen height. if still (text height < screen height) I loop through the string and do the same thing in a while loop.

Every thing went well, but when it comes to the end of the string I get IndexOutOfBoundsException. I have attached the screenshot of the Logcat  below.

[image]

The code I used to get the no of pages is like this

```
public String getNoOfPages(String text){


    String remainingString = "";

    try{
        int screenHeight = getScreenHeight();
        String originalText = text;
        String strToModify = text;


        StringBuilder newString = new StringBuilder();
        StringBuilder oldString = new StringBuilder();


        int startIndex = 0;
        String strToFind = " ";
        int index = strToModify.indexOf(strToFind,startIndex);

        newString.append(originalText.substring(startIndex, index+1));
        oldString.append(newString.toString());
        startIndex = index+1;

        int textHeight = getTextHeight(newString.toString());

        while(textHeight < screenHeight){
            index = strToModify.indexOf(strToFind,startIndex);
            oldString.replace(0,oldString.toString().length(),newString.toString());
            newString.append(originalText.substring(startIndex, index+1));
            startIndex = index+1;
            textHeight = getTextHeight(newString.toString());
        }

        remainingString = originalText.substring(oldString.length()-1,originalText.length());

    }catch(Exception e){
        Log.d("chathura123","Error in getNoOfPages  " );
        e.printStackTrace();

    }

    return remainingString; 
}
```

The logic is when the remaining string is an empty string("") ,it means that is the end of the content of the page. So I want to check until it returns an empty string.

The above method is called inside another while loop. (In Async Task)
    String tmp = null;

```
        try{
             tmp = reader.getNoOfPages(content);

             while (!tmp.equals("")) {

                 tmp = reader.getNoOfPages(tmp);
                 page_count++;

                 if(page_count==80){
                     Log.d("chathura123", "80 th iteration");
                 }

                 Log.d("chathura123", "inside while "+page_count);
             }

        }catch(Exception e){
            Log.d("chathura123", "error occured in getPageCount");
        }
```

What is the wrong with this? Why I am getting OutOfBoundsException?

Thank you.

Comment: when are you expecting `while(textHeight < screenHeight)` loop to end?

Comment: Initially I am getting Screen Height of the device. And while appending the texts I get the new text height  is still less than screen height. If not that is the end of loop. That means the text is the content to fit the screen size.(we can say a single page)

Comment: may be on the last line, when there are no characters there is an error for `originalText.substring(startIndex, index+1)` what if `originalText` doesnt have `index+1` index

Comment: yes, Since I am checking for spaces, since there are no spaces after the last space of the last line, I want to consider that point as well. At the next iteration it will give -1 since there are no spaces. That might be the case.

Comment: @SagarPilkhwal Yes, As I mentioned in the above comment that was the issue. Thanks for pointing out that one.

Comment: so now is the problem resolved ?

Comment: try `if(originalText.length() < index+1)
 {
  newString.append(originalText.substring(startIndex, index));
 }else
 {
  newString.append(originalText.substring(startIndex, index+1));
 }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

may be on the last line, when there are no characters there is an error for `originalText.substring(startIndex, index+1)` what if `originalText` doesnt have `index+1` length/index.